# Cannot connect to mysql by 'localhost' only via '127.0.0.1'

Tags: server, mysql

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 with LAMP on VPN. Sometimes on my website I was receiving `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused` and I read that I should connect by `localhost` instead `127.0.0.1`, but it was causing:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)`
```

I checked and there is no `mysqld.sock` file. I tried reinstalling mysql and configuring my.cnf, but nothing helped. Oddly, on my home computer (same configuration) I can execute `mysql --host=localhost` without any problems and also I have `mysqld.sock` in `/var/run/mysqld`.

What can I do to make socket will exist and I will be able to connect `localhost` on VPN?

Comment: Did you simply reinstall mysql or did you purge it beforehand?

Comment: Is the user running `mysqld` able to write to `/var/run/mysqld`?

Comment: @FatalMerlin I was reinstalling without purging, but I will backup data and try it. @ridgy folder have perms 755, owner and group are `mysql`

Comment: @FatalMerlin after reinstalling with purge, socket file exist and I can connect by `localhost`. Problem solved :)

Comment: Please make an answer with the solution instead of putting it into the question! https://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full reinstall with purge helped:

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common mysql-server-core-5.7 mysql-client-core-5.7
sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql /var/lib/mysql
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Now `mysqld.sock` file exists and I can connect via `localhost`.